# Check Identity of SSL Certificate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsurlconnection

I'm very new to this field... I've recently ran into a problem... I want to check if the SSL certificate which is coming from the server is coming from the correct server (our own server) or it is coming from any malicious server... How can I achieve that? I'm using `NSURLConnection` delegate methods `connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:` and `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:`.

Answer (score 3):

Use below code in connection delegate and replace `YOUR HOST` string with your real host.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
    {
        if ([@"YOUR HOST" isEqualToString:challenge.protectionSpace.host])
        {
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] 
                 forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];         
        }
    }   
    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS5 and greater, and to fail:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
    {
        if ([@"xip.comcast.net" isEqualToString:challenge.protectionSpace.host] ||
            [@"xip-staging.cim.comcast.net" isEqualToString:challenge.protectionSpace.host])
        {
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust]
                 forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
        else
        {
            [challenge.sender cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
    }
    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```